# Java convention with regard to code format

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions, convention

Is it allowed in Java convention to write such code:

```
public void nameOfTheFunction()
{

}
```

A lot of people said me that it is prohibited according to Java code convention and that my code should look like:

```
public void nameOfTheFunction(){

}
```

But I did not find any info about this.

Comment: This is really just personal choice of style.

Comment: Both are ok. The second is more frequent, but the first is ok too. You can take a look at Oracle recommendations if you want : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: The second one is the Sun/Oracle coding standard.  It's tighter, more succinct.  The first one is common for .NET and C# developers.  I prefer the second, but it's subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is oracle(/java) convention

see [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Quote:

Class and Interface Declarations
When coding Java classes and interfaces, the following formatting rules should be followed:
• No space between a method name and the parenthesis “(“ starting its parameter list
• Open brace “{” appears at the end of the same line as the declaration statement
• Closing brace “}” starts a line by itself indented to match its corresponding opening
statement, except when it is a null statement the “}” should appear immediately after the
“{“

```
class Sample extends Object {
 int ivar1;
 int ivar2;
 Sample(int i, int j) {
   ivar1 = i;
   ivar2 = j;
 }
 int emptyMethod() {}
 ...
}
```

Comment: What is a null statement?

Comment: if you have an empty method e.g. empty constructor you don't add new line and write MyClass() {}

Answer (score 2):

It's personal preference, plain and simple.

There are many people who tout their preferred style as the "one and only", but in reality it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Google Java styleguide: [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1.2-blocks-k-r-style)

This is the Oracle styleguide: [Oracle Java Style Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

It doesn't really make a difference. You can do what you like the most. In Java however most people write the bracket on the same line as the rest (I personally prefer this as well :)